# Increase max request content size on Linux in AWS (.Net Core 6)

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core

How do I increase the max request body size so that my .Net Core 6 web app (Linux in AWS) can process large REST payloads?

None of these solutions work:

1. Setting serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null when configuring Kestrel.
2. Setting serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = null when configuring Kestrel.
3. Setting attribute RequestSizeLimit on API method.
4. Setting attribute DisableRequestSizeLimit on API method.

This is my code to configure the web app:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
              {                  
                  webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                  {
                      serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null; //unlimited
                      serverOptions.Limits.MaxRequestBufferSize = null;                       
                  })                  
                      .UseStartup<Startup>();                  
              });
```

Comment: Why? How large? What is the actual problem? Turning off limits is the hack, not the solution. The limits are there to prevent DoS attacks. AWS itself will prevent large bodies. Simply turning off the limit won't fix the real problem

Comment: What happens if the upload is broken halfway through a 100MB file? Will you start from scratch? That's a problem solved since the 1990s, using range requests -  you upload files in parts. If something goes wrong you won't have to reupload the already uploaded parts. You can even upload parts concurrently. AWS S3 and similar services depend on this to upload and download large files

Comment: There isn't a "real problem". It isn't a "hack". I need to increase the maximum payload size.